# Divide and round only if numeric within a column in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, rounding

My dataframe contains columns with both numeric values and strings, such as "n.a." for example.

Within each of these columns, if a value is numeric, I want to convert it to millions and then round it, otherwise I want to leave it as it is.

```
                 2015               2016
1           216683720          185611751
2           381416280          271288249
3             7700000           11150000
4           843200000          864800000
5             2400000            2400000
6          1292300000         1264400000
7            38940000           27900000
8            69908032           74742601
9            82891968           78057399
10           29030000           47600000
11           22900000           12700000
12             270000             300000
13           13482407           11131336
14           72244071           40934757
15             500000             500000
16             500000             500000
17             500000             500000
18               n.a.               n.a.
```

I tried this to convert to millions and round, only for the numeric values of the columns:

```
y_te[c("2015","2016")] <- lapply(y_te[c("2015","2016")], function(n) ifelse(is.numeric(n), n/(1000000), n))
y_te[c("2015","2016")] <- lapply(y_te[c("2015","2016")], function(n) ifelse(is.numeric(n), round(n, 1), n))
```

However, this is what I get:

```
 2015      2016
1  216683720 185611751
2  216683720 185611751
3  216683720 185611751
4  216683720 185611751
5  216683720 185611751
6  216683720 185611751
7  216683720 185611751
8  216683720 185611751
9  216683720 185611751
10 216683720 185611751
11 216683720 185611751
12 216683720 185611751
13 216683720 185611751
14 216683720 185611751
15 216683720 185611751
16 216683720 185611751
17 216683720 185611751
18 216683720 185611751
```

What is wrong? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~"2015", ~"2016",
  "216683720"     ,     "185611751",
  "381416280"      ,    "271288249",
  "7700000 "       ,   "11150000",
  "n.a"            ,   "n.a"
)  
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ round(as.numeric(.x)/1000000, 1)))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   `2015` `2016`
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  217.   186. 
#> 2  381.   271. 
#> 3    7.7   11.2
#> 4   NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I do not understand why, when I run your code on my dataframe, values do not get rounded.
This is why I am trying:

  y_te %>% mutate(across(c("2015","2016"), ~ round(as.numeric(.x)/1000000, 1)))

Comment: Can you provided me a small sample of your data? `dput(head(dataframe))`

Comment: @TomHoel  See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/scoped.html) and [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) for reasons why new code should use `across` rather than a scoped verb, and an explanation of why the change was made.